# PrimeNg p-table column resizing in grouping not working

Tags: angular, html-table, angular6, primeng

> The primeng p-table resizable column issue

```
 <p-table [resizableColumns]="true" columnResizeMode="expand" [value]="data" sortMode="multiple" [style]="{width:'100%'}" [scrollable]="true" [scrollHeight]="height" [columns]="columnList" (onColResize)="onBusinessLogicTableColResize($event)">
      <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
        <colgroup>
          <col *ngFor="let col of groupHeaderColSpan" [style.width]="col.width + 'px'">
        </colgroup>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <th *ngFor="let col of columnList" [colSpan]="col.colSpan" [rowSpan]="col.rowSpan" pResizableColumn>
            {{col?.header}}
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <ng-template ngFor let-col [ngForOf]="columnList">
            <th *ngFor="let subheader of col?.subheaders" [colSpan]="subheader.colSpan" [rowSpan]="subheader.rowSpan">
              {{subheader?.header}}
            </th>
          </ng-template>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-columnValue let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columns="columns">
        <ng-template ngFor let-col [ngForOf]="columns">
          <ng-template [ngIf]="col.hasOwnProperty('subheaders')" [ngIfElse]="showData">
            <td class="ui-resizable-column" *ngFor="let sub of col.subheaders" class="text-center">
              {{columnValue[sub.field]}}
            </td>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #showData>
            <td class="ui-resizable-column">
              {{columnValue[col.field]}}
            </td>
          </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
    </p-table>





    The column list will be like this 
         columnList = [
            {
              header: "header1", field: "header1", subheaders: [
                { header: "subheader1", field: "subheader1" },
                { header: "subheader2", field: "subheader2" }
              ]
            }
          ]


    groupHeaderColSpan = [
    { field: 'subheader1', width: '100', child: 2 }
    ]
```

> I want to apply the re-sizable column to the table, So I have applied
>   it but not working properly as I increase the width of particular
>   column but it increases the width of another column.

[image: The table will look like this]

[image]

> in 2nd image I tried to increase the width of MAT column but it increases the width of sub column